# why forms must be used when redirect to pages with POST

Tags: asp.net, forms, rest, post

Quote from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230722/post-action-for-url-action)

> You can't use POST by simply navigating to a different URL. (Which is
>   what you'd do by changing location.href.)
>
> Using POST only makes sense when submitting some data. It's not clear
>   from your code what data would actually be POSTed.
>
> If you really want to initiate a POST via javascript try using it to
>   submit a form.

I do not understand why POST is so different. What is the motivation of designing that POST cannot be done without form? Just remind people never to forget to submit some data?

Comment: GET and POST simply have different intended purposes, that's all. There are several other HTTP methods as well, e.g. PUT, DELETE etc. Bear in mind a HTML form can submit using any HTTP method you specify, including GET. window.location.href specifically always initiates a GET, because it's intended to be equivalent to typing the URL into your browser's address bar manually, and doing that always launches a GET. You can still pass information via a GET, using querystring parameters, but there are limitations to it (size of data, privacy issues), hence why other HTTP methods such as POST exist

Comment: BTW a POST _can_ be done without a form, if you use AJAX. Or you could create a hidden form and use JS to programatically submit that form as a full postback, so it's transparent to the user. But why exactly do you _want_ to use it without a form, anyway? What's the problem you're facing? These are just different methods for different purposes, that's all really. Maybe you should read this (there are also many other resources online about HTTP methods which you can search for, as well): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Comment: @ADyson I was confused about some points and your comment made me more clear. However, I still believe there should be a general method for navigating URLs with all HTTP methods. Hidden form or Ajax do work for POST, but still feels a little bit bothered. What if POST can be integrated in to "GET-only" methods like `window.location.href` or `HTML.Actionlink` in C#? This will be more convenient right? Form can be a way but should not be the only way for non-ajax POST. Anyway, I know this is just my personal API design choice. I just wonder those original designers' idea.

Comment: Like I said, the exact purpose of window.location.href and of Actionlink (which generates an `<a href` hyperlink of course), is to automate what the user would do by typing in the address bar, i.e. generate a GET request. That's the rationale for it as far as I know. It's easy enough with a bit of JS to create a hyperlink where the default behaviour is suppressed and it actually submits a hidden form in the background using POST. I agree it might be nicer if there was a consistent interface for all method types. Perhaps you can submit a proposal to W3C to update the standards in future :-).