# Asp.net Core Url.Action() does not hit my controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have spent quite a while trying to figure out why my breakpoint in the `ExternalLoginCallback` method is not being hit.

Below is my code inside my AccountController:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl});
    var properties = signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
}
```

I have specified the method name, controller name and parameter inside `Url.Action()` but `ExternalLoginCallback` is not being hit why is this?

I have tried removing the `remoteError` parameter, but it still will not get hit.

Comment: You can't use POST by simply navigating to a different URL. 

Using POST only makes sense when submitting some data. It's not clear from your code what data would actually be POSTed.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2230764/9936356

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. I removed the HttpPost attribute.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your method ExternalLoginCallback expects to receive the parameter "returnUrl" and you are posting "ReturnUrl" (uppercase).

You can try other tests, like change the method ExternalLoginCallback to receive a GET instead a POST...