# How to set a hyperlink <a> with a method call to post in the controller instead of the main <input type="submit"> in the view? (ASP-NET.MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can't figure out how a specific input in the view calls the post method. I need to remove an `<input type="submit">` element. I will only use link buttons `<a>`. But I don't know how to call the standard methods `HttpPost` in the controller.
Thanks

Comment: "I will only use link buttons"... why? Can't you just style the submit button to be link-like?

Comment: I have buttons with icons in a row. It is impossible to make the input identical - the input with pictures has problems. Result: https://ibb.co/RBmfpzR

Comment: @Nik Volk:  You can do it with solution provided here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/6265100/6630084](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6265100/6630084)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [post action for url.action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230722/post-action-for-url-action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. Need to add not a hyperlink `<a>`, but a `<button>`